# Separate Login Page for Windows Azure Access Control Service

Tags: azure, accesscontrolservice

I set up Windows Azure Access Control Service on my local web app so that I can login through Google, and everything works fine.

What I would like to do is allow certain pages to be viewed anonymously. Whenever I try to open the app, I am taken to the ACS login page even if the controller / action I am trying to execute is not decorated with an `Authorize` attribute.

Ideally I would like unauthenticated users to be taken to the ACS login page only when they click on some "Login" link or if they try to go to a restricted area, much like how the default MVC identity system works.

Comment: Isn't this done via `<authorization />` configuration under `<system.web>` in the `web.config` file?

Comment: Did you apply the Authorize attribute at some other place that is getting inherited by all pages/controller methods? Possibly on a base controller class or something like that?